# What is a good practice and how to improve my solution of splitting environments?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, environment

I've decided on splitting my environments keeping them in .js files in an environment folder and keep all the sensitive information in .env file *(use a third-party module 'DOTENV')*

That's what I've come up with but I understand that it's not the best practice and there are a lot of things which should have been implemented in a completely different way but I just lack experience and practice.

At first, I tried to use as more " for loop " as it's possible because as far as I know, it's the fastest way to loop through an object, but in some cases, it was much easier to with "map or filter".

It doesn't look nice to assign data by returning a Promise. Maybe there is a way to get data without a Promise?

I would appreciate any suggestions on how the code can be improved and good practices, your experience.

And I am not sure if I used logging right and error handling. That's a completely new thing for me at the moment, but I used "try catch" to catch them and simply logged them on the console and put into a file.

*code:*

```
import { readdirSync } from 'fs';
import path from "path";
import { logger } from '../src/utils/logging';
import { merge } from "lodash";

// FIXME: Function returns a Promise with the data.
// It's not comfortable and seem a bad practice - too much code for a simple task,
// and deal with a promise what may outcome in decreasing perfomance
// ( The simplest code, the fastest code )
export let env = getEnvironment().then(
  res => { return res },
  err => logger.error(err)
);

// TODO: Rewrite this function into a class Environment to keep it organized and implement ES6 standart
async function getEnvironment() {
  const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
  const rootPath = process.cwd();
  const folder = 'environment';

  const loadEnvironments = () => {

    // Getting the list of available environments in the "environment" folder,
    // at the same time excluding index.js file
    const list = readdirSync(path.join(rootPath, folder)).filter(file => !/(?=^(index.js))/i.test(file));
    const parameters = {};

    // Loading the files found in the folder,
    // merging them with the help of a "lodash" library
    // just to get one common Object with all possible parameters from all found environments
    const loaded = list.map(fileName => {
      let name = fileName.split('.')[0];
      let loadedFile = require(path.join(rootPath, folder, fileName));
      const file = loadedFile[name];
      merge(parameters, { ...file });
      return loadedFile;
    });

    // Picking the currect mode out of already loaded ones
    const current = { ...loaded.filter(file => file[mode]).map(file => file[mode])[0] };

    // Returning an object with all parameters
    return {
      parameters,
      current
    }
  };

  const environments = loadEnvironments();

  const environment = {} = looping(environments.parameters, environments.current);


  function looping(obj, values) {
    const collection = {};

    for (const key in obj) {

      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

        if (typeof obj[key] !== 'object') {

          try {
            if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

              // By a recursive function run through all parameters,
              // transforming the keys to uppercased,
              // assigning value to 'obj' (file containing all the parameters)
              // from the current mode
              collection[key.toUpperCase()] = values[key];
            } else {

              // if there is no such a key in the current mode,
              // 'null' is assigned
              collection[key.toUpperCase()] = null;
            }
          } catch (e) {
            logger.error(` Missing parameter "${key.toUpperCase()}" in ${mode} mode!!!`);
          }

        } else {

          // Recursing through the object and the nested objects
          collection[key.toUpperCase()] = looping(obj[key], values[key]);
        }
      }
    }
    return collection;
  }

  // When parameters are ready,
  // the current mode is assigned
  environment["MODE"] = mode;

  return environment;
}
```

Comment: Requests for refactoring advise for working code should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Taplar, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: Jus a suggestion, you could have your common config in an index.js file, and then having specific configuration in separate files, then you could merge the common config with the needed file based on the mode. Did not post it as an answer since I am unsure if it would fit your need but I could do it if you want

Comment: @Taplar, apparently I can post it once in 40 minutes. So next time I will know that. And what is this site for? Solving problems with the code or something?

Comment: S.O. is intended to be a question and answer site for coding *issues*.  "Issues" on S.O. are defined around non-working code.  More indepth: [StackOverflow ontopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Taplar, got it! thanks

Comment: @Faros, I've got your idea. Yes, I think that may be useful in some cases to have common parameters for all environments. So you have any issues on the code and implementation in what I've got?

Comment: @Taplar, if you don't mind, I don't an issue with the code above. I need to return data from a Promise in each and every file I'm importing it. Is this the right behaviour  and how can I get data so I don't need to deal with a Promise in every file I use environment variables?

Comment: Err, files don't return promises.  The script in the file that you import and execute may have logic that returns promises.

Comment: @Taplar, yes, I meant that. but I have a function which returns an object. But when I'm importing the file, it imports the variable with a Promise. I don't know why it happens

Comment: Which function are you referencing?  Is that method in your current question?

Comment: @Taplar, I import variable export let env = getEnvironment()

Comment: The variable gets a promise most likely due to your usage of `async` in defining the function

Comment: @Taplar, oh, I can see now. I didn't know that async return a Promise. Thanks a lot for your help!!!